# Excel Line chart multiple related series, colouring

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm using MS Excel 2010.

I have a worksheet that looks like this

```
---/ 1001 / 1002 / 1003 / 1101 / 1102 / 1201 / 1202 / 1203 / 1204
R2 / ... 
R3 / ...
...
```

I would like to create a line chart with each column a series but coloured so that all series with the same first two digits are the same colour but different shades (so 10** would all be red (say) but increasingly lighter shades of red).

Any suggestions? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Sub ColorLines()

  Dim objSeries As series

  Dim strLastDigits As String

  Dim lngColorIndex As Long

  lngColorIndex = 2
  strLastDigits = ""

  For Each objSeries In Diagramm1.SeriesCollection

    If Left(objSeries.Name, 2) <> strLastDigits Then
      'set new color
      lngColorIndex = lngColorIndex + 1
      objSeries.Border.ColorIndex = lngColorIndex
    Else
      'set shade of current color
      If objSeries.Border.Color > 50 Then
        objSeries.Border.Color = objSeries.Border.Color - 50
      End If
    End If

    strLastDigits = Left(objSeries.Name, 2)
  Next objSeries

End Sub
```

BUT - the concrete algorithm to automate the shading and coloring is up to you ;)

This is just an example, of how you could do this.

Comment: Sorry, but what does "Diagramm1." do?

Comment: oh, jeah, this is my chart-object, you can replace it with some other chart-object - like `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)` or whatever suits your needs.